# .htaccess redirect from user to new subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all links for a site that looks like:  www.domain.com/~me to subdomain.newdomain.org/.  I only have access to the .htaccess file under my subfolder on domain.com and not the root .htaccess file.  I can get it so that I redirect links like www.domain.com/~me/page2.html to the root subdomain.newdomain.org or to subdomain.newdomain.org/~me/page2.html, but I can't figure out how to get to subdomain.newdomain.com/page2.html.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  (Ideally the user would still see www.domain.com/~me, but this is not entirely necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

You must select the part after `~me` in a capture group and append that to your new domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^~me/(.+) http://subdomain.newdomain.org/$1 [L]
```